# How to fire an event after two different radio buttons are selected

Tags: jquery

I have two groups of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="2"/>

<input type="radio" name="book" value="fiction"/>
<input type="radio" name="book" value="novel"/>
```

```js
function myEvent(){
    //do something
}
```

I want to fire an event, specifically a call to another function when both radio buttons are checked. I've tried using the `click()`, and `change()` functions, however, the call to the function occurs after the first radio button is checked. I want to call a function only after both radio buttons are checked. How do I do this?

Comment: slap onclick handlers on all of them, then have the handler count how many radio buttons are selected and only proceed if both sets are.

Comment: @MarcB Should be `onchange` for inputs so it also picks up keyboard use.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$(':radio').change(function() {
    if($(':radio:checked').length === 2) {
        myEvent();
    }
});
```

The key part is the `if` statement, which selects all `checked` radio buttons, then makes sure there's exactly two of them (using the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object), before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':radio').change(function() {
    if ($("input:radio[name='name']").is(':checked') && $("input:radio[name='book']").is(':checked')) {
         myEvent();
    }
}
```