# javascript jquery fire an event after two inputs are changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two inputs in my page, I wanna fire an event if these 2 inputs are modified.
In stackoverflow, I find how to do that for radio buttons

[How to fire an event after two different radio buttons are selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383089/how-to-fire-an-event-after-two-different-radio-buttons-are-selected)

but not for inputs.
my code is here:

```
        ...

        <tr>
            <td class="td-header">From</td>
            <td class="td_content"><input type="text" id="debutDate"
                onclick="changeTime('debutDate');" class="input_tag"  style="width:227px"
                name="debutDate" readonly="readonly"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-header">To</td>
            <td class="td_content"><input type="text" id="fin_date"  style="width:227px"
                onclick="changeTime('fin_date');" readonly="readonly" class="input_tag" name="fin_date"></td>
        </tr>
        ....
```

if these two fields are modified, I wanna calculate the number of days between the two dates inserted then set it in a label tag.
I have the function to calculate the number Of  days:

```
function calculerNbreJours() {
    var d1 = new Date($("#debutDate").datepicker("getDate"));       
    var d2 = new Date($("#fin_date").datepicker("getDate"));
    $("#nbreJours").val(nombreJoursEntreDeuxDates(d1, d2));
}

function nombreJoursEntreDeuxDates(d1, d2){
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var firstDate = new Date(d1);
    var secondDate = new Date(d2);
    var day = secondDate.getDay();
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)))+1;
    return diffDays;
}
```

Briefly, I wanna call `calculerNbreJours` just after the two inputs have changed!

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What do you mean by input? checkbox? text? number?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: @junior  Are you want to fire an event only if both input are changed?

Comment: I have changed my question. I m sorry

Comment: @Tanmay, yes just if the two inputs are changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the generic solution which supports N number of controls.

```js
$(".controls").change(function(){
$(this).attr("data-changed",true);
  if($(".controls").length == $(".controls[data-changed='true']").length) {
   //Do your work here.
   alert("All controls chnaged");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="controls"/>
<input type="text" class="controls"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ll try that :)